# What shadow (or light, or renderer) attribute have I scale to get fine shadow?

Tags: three.js

[Bad shadow on the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kywXy.jpg)

Window frame in the scene has dimensions approx. 1500х2000. When I on point light shadows looks terrible. I think I have scale some shadowMap or another parameters but dont know which.

I use PointLight placed very far because I didnt success in Directional Light shadows.

```js
light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xf5eccf, 1 );
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadow.camera.far = 80000;
light.position.set( 20000, 20000, 50000 );
light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
 
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
```

Comment: your shadow camera parameters need to be as tight around your scene as possible. Does the `shadow.camera.far` need to be that high? Is your scene extending to 80000?

Comment: Objects placed at 0,0,0. Light source placed at 20000,20000,50000. Ок, I set shadow.camera.far = 60000 because the source distance ~57450. But no effect.


light.shadow.camera.near = 55000;
light.shadow.camera.far = 60000;

Comment: what is the bounding of your object?

Comment: gaitat, thanks but I understood that problem is not in high scale. I scale all dimensions in scene 0.001 times to ordinary sizes, but no effects. I read that the problem concerned self-shadowing. My window frame is one object that have cast and receive shadow. Is it possible to do it without artifacts? Dont know yet. Lets google.